# NoMethodError: undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for devise_invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rubygems

I am using a gem devise_invitable. I just want to re-invite an user. However, for such a simple operation I got an error:

```
[10] pry(#<MyController>)> @user = User.invite!("user1@test.com", current_user)
NoMethodError: undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for "user1@test.com":String
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise_invitable-1.3.3/lib/devise_invitable/model.rb:252:in `invite!'
```

I tried to include the 2 files that might solve this but I couldn't because they didn't exist:

```
[11] pry(#<MyController>)> require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'
=> false

[13] pry(#<MyController>)> require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access'
=> false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
@user = User.invite!({email: "user1@test.com"}, current_user)
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: unexpected ')', expecting =>`

Comment: it should be @user = User.invite!({email: "user1@test.com"}, current_user)